# Is there any scriptural injunction that says leaving wife and family for attaining God-realisation is a sin?

Tags: scripture, sin

Our scriptures depict a general person of the Kaliyuga as: *'stridevah kamakimkarah'* i.e. who obeys wife as God and is a passion of lust.

Is there any scriptural injunction also that says leaving wife and family for attaining God-realisation is a sin?

Comment: Like entering Sannyasa?

Comment: @Ikshvaku yes.......

Comment: it is definitely not a sin. but there are some conditions. to obtain sanyasa when brahmachari, man needs to obtain mother's permission. see story of adi shankara. to obtain sanyasa when gruhastha, man needs to obtain wife's permission. of course, the 'permission' is restricted to progeny. wealth, knowledge. wife cannot simply say 'i just won't let you go' without putting conditions. see upanishads for story about rishi leaving 2 wives.

Comment: @ram yes as the case of Yajnavalka